admob-plus-cordova AppOpen Ad not display on app launch (Android)
I'm trying to implement Admob App Open Ads using admob-plus-cordova and did exactly what it says on Website (https://admob-plus.github.io/docs/cordova/ads/app-open)
But ad doesn't open on app launch but it opens on if app minimized to background and bring back to foreground.
Here is code that i have
   document.addEventListener('deviceready', async () => {

      await window['admob'].start()

      const ad =  new window['admob'].AppOpenAd({
        adUnitId: 'APP_OPEN_ID',
        
      })

      ad.on('load', (evt) => {
        console.log(evt)
      })
      ad.on('loadfail', (evt) => {
        console.log(evt)
      })

      // NOTE should load ad when app launch
      await ad.load();

      document.addEventListener(
        'resume',
        async () => {
          // NOTE `resume` event is triggered when app back to foreground
          if (!await ad.show()) {
            await ad.load()
          }
        },
        false,
      )
    }, false);

But I want to make app appear on app launch. Can you help me?
